# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics.regression'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pip, sklearn-pandas

trying to do the following import:

```
from sklearn.metrics.regression import mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error, r2_score
```

and I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.metrics.regression'
```

tried fixing with the installation of:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn scipy matplotlib
```

but I don't think that's what I'm missing since it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking to import them from `sklearn.metrics`, not `sklearn.metrics.regression`

[Link to the library](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is:

```py
from sklearn import metrics 

metrics.mean_absolute_error(<your params here>)
metrics.mean_squared_error(<your params here>)
metrics.r2_score(<your params here>)
```

##### Edit

you can check the attributes of the metrics instance with:

```py
dir(metrics)
```